# Как разделить строку на столбики? Python

Tags: python, строки, list, разделение-строк

У меня есть, допустим, такая строка:

```
s='''
# #   #
###  # # 
# #   #
'''
```

Как сделать, чтобы из неё создался список по столбикам, то есть, примерно такой:

```
s2=['''
#
#
#
''',
'''

#

''',
...
]
```

**P. S.** Пустые столбики тоже надо сделать

Comment: а как из первого получается второе?

Comment: Вот я и спрашиваю

Comment: вы спрашиваете как это сделать программно, а я спрашиваю какая вообще связь между первым и вторым. Какой алгоритм

Comment: @Эникейщик есть связь: два первые элемента списка - два первые "столбика" шириной в 1 элемент, то есть куски буквы `Н`

Comment: Для начала надо понять, как задана ширина изображения строки в первом коде. Это одна строка? Или список строк?

Comment: Это одна расширенная строка

Comment: Но длится она до конца буквы `O`, дальше там нет пробелов.

Comment: А почему вы её отображаете именно так? Видимо, имеете в виду заданную ширину

Comment: Тогда без дополнительной информации интерпретировать её можно разными способами

Comment: Ну покажите хоть один :))

Comment: Строку `# #   ####  # ## #   #` можно порезать на кусочки и вывести в несколько строк разными способами, столбики тоже будут разными.

Comment: Не сплюснутую))) Как у меня

Comment: Ладно, я пас...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм... Это что ли?

```
from itertools import zip_longest

stolbiki = list(map("\n".join, zip_longest(*s.split("\n"), fillvalue="")))
```

```
['\n#\n#\n#\n',
 '\n \n#\n \n',
 '\n#\n#\n#\n',
 '\n \n \n \n',
 '\n \n \n \n',
 '\n \n#\n \n',
 '\n#\n \n#\n',
 '\n\n#\n\n',
 '\n\n \n\n']
```

Comment: Да, спасибо Вам большое!)

Answer (score 0):

```
s = s[1:]  # убираю ненужный снос строки вначале
arr = s.split("\n")  # делю на строки
length = len(max(arr))  # длина максимально длинной строки
s2 = ["" for i in range(length)]  # s2
for i in range(length):
    s2[i] = "\n" + "\n".join([(arr[j][i] if len(arr[j]) > i else '') for j in range(3)]) + "\n"
    # j - итератор по строкам
    # если строка по индексу j достаточно длинная, беру из неё символ. Иначе пустой символ.
```

```
['\n#\n#\n#\n',
 '\n \n#\n \n',
 '\n#\n#\n#\n',
 '\n \n \n \n',
 '\n \n \n \n',
 '\n \n#\n \n',
 '\n#\n \n#\n',
 '\n\n#\n\n',
 '\n\n \n\n']
```

Этот код работает с примерами вроде вашего. Где вначале стоит снос строки, а колонки разной длины.